# Pointer to non static member variable as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

It looked like question 6880832 pointer-to-class-member-as-template-parameter had the answer to my problem but it doesn't answer how to reference the pointer within the templated class. I have got this far:

```
template<typename C, typename T, T C::*m, int direction>
class Cmp {
private:
    bool isAscend = direction;
public:

    bool operator()(const C* lhs, const C* rhs) {
        return isAscend ?
            rhs->m > lhs->m :
            lhs->m > rhs->m;
    }// bool operator()(const UnRecTran* lhs,const UnRecTran* rhs)

};// class Cmp
Cmp<UnRecTran, shrtDate, &UnRecTran::date, true>
```

(I am trying to do comparisons on UnRecTran::date values in this particular instantiation). However, I get "'m': is not a member of 'UnRecTran'".

Is what i am trying to do even possible? I understood that the "address" of a member variable was constant - it being just the offset from the beginning of the object rather than a physical (runtime) address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for accessing member data through a pointer-to-member is:

```
obj.*m_ptr //obj is class type
p_obj->*m_ptr //p_obj is pointer to obj
```

Your operator should probably look like this:

```
bool operator()(const C* lhs, const C* rhs) {
    return isAscend ?
        rhs->*m > lhs->*m :
        lhs->*m > rhs->*m;
}
```

Comment: @TartLlama Thanks for that. I had tried dereferencing m but got "
'specialization': cannot convert from 'int UnRecTran::* ' to 'shrtDate UnRecTran::* ' " directed at the instantiation (last line of code).

Comment: @willofirony Can't really help you with that error without seeing the declarations, but I'd guess that `date` is declared as `int` rather than `shrtDate` or something.

Comment: @TartLlarma Got it. You were 100% correct on the dereferencing. The original class to be sorted had a shrtDate member but I had made up a dummy class with an int member (to simplify the debug - yes I did write simplify). After a bunch of other "simplifications" it had got lost. The template is now working generically. Thank you